# Is it possible to add a new line in a non-spatial table using Qgis?

Tags: qgis, spatialite, dbf

While using QGIS, and having loaded a non spatial table (from a dbf or a Spatialite table), is it possible to add a new row to its table attributes?

Normally in a spatial layer you have to use "add features button", that obviouslly won't work in this case.

My idea was to use Qgis as somekind of frontend to a Spatialite database, with the ability to edit\add features in spatial tables as well in the non-spatial ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.8 there should be an add button in the attribute table

[image]

Comment: hmm... I don't have it. May be it is in trunk?

Comment: Yeah maybe it is only in master

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Guess I will have to wait until it become stable. Thanks

Comment: The button is available in the stable version 1.8.0-3, installed with OSGeo4W.

Comment: If someone don't want to open the attribute table each time he needs to add a new line, an alternative to this answer was given in this [question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44000/button-to-add-a-new-line-in-a-non-spatial-table-without-opening-the-table-itself)

Answer (score 4):

With a DB Manager (unless your spatialite version is 3) you are able to execute any query including INSERT, so yes (plus there is spatialite-gui-plugin, but again spatilite 3 is not supported). But I prefer to use for this [spatialite-gui](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite_gui/index) in parralel with QGIS. Changes are synchronised nicely (at least so far for me).