# Button to add a new line in a non-spatial table without opening the table itself using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

While using QGIS and having loaded a non spatial table (from PostGIS), is it possible to add a new row to its table attributes without having to open the attribute table first as in here [Is it possible to add a new line in a non-spatial table using Qgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32455/is-it-possible-to-add-a-new-line-in-a-non-spatial-table-using-qgis)

Same principle as add a point but with no geometry, just information in a table.

I was able to create a plugin that chooses and starts editing the table but can't get the form window to open so I can fill the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do it. Here is the code i used

```
# Import the PyQt and QGIS libraries
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

import resources_rc

class SelectFeaturesPlugin:

def __init__(self, iface):
    # Save reference to the QGIS interface
    self.iface = iface

def initGui(self):

    # Create action that will start plugin configuration
    self.action5 = QAction(QIcon(":/plugins/selectfeatures/icon.png"), u"Add Record", self.iface.mainWindow())
    # connect the action to the run method
    QObject.connect(self.action5, SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.addRecord)

    # Add toolbar button and menu item
    self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action5)
    self.iface.addPluginToMenu(u"&Add Record", self.action5)

def unload(self):
    # Remove the plugin menu item and icon
    self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action5)    
    self.iface.removePluginMenu(u"&Add Record",self.action5)

# run method that performs all the real work
def addRecord(self):
    feat = QgsFeature()
    layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
    layer.startEditing()
    layer.addFeature( feat )

    from myattrdialog import AttributeDialog
    dlg = AttributeDialog( layer )
    if not dlg.exec_():
      return

    #Populate the feature attrs map usin the values the user inserted in the dialog
    feat.setAttributeMap( dlg.getFeatureAttributeMap() )
    layer.commitChanges()
```